# REST API status code for upstream service failure?

Tags: rest, http

Designing a RESTful API which has some elements that depend on upstream services (e.g. database, another web service, etc).  In the case where the application itself is in a valid state, and can still be used, but one of those upstream services cannot be reached (either due to a network issue, or whatever), is there a more appropriate status code to use than HTTP 500?

HTTP 500 feels inappropriate to me because the problem isn't (as the RFC defines) an "internal server error". The server is fine, and still able to process other requests without melting down, it's just got degraded functionality until that other service comes back online.

I thought about `502 - Bad Gateway` because the application is effectively acting as a proxy for this other service (kinda), or perhaps `503 - Service Unavailable` since it's a service which is in fact unavailable, but they didn't feel exactly right.  Especially the last one, since it has the connotation of being unavailable due to load or too many requests to process.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You shouldn't look at it from your (the api providers) perspective, but rather from the consumers perspective. You should be able to explain to your consumers how they should act when receiving a specific status code. How should they behave differently from when you send a 500?

As an api consumer, I really don't care where things went wrong. I have a single interface to work with and that is your public api. How you have chosen to implement the api behind this interface is irrelevant to me.

So for all I know, you had an internal server error. You weren't able to process my request even though it was totally legit. So you should return a status code 500 even if this was caused by a downstream system.

If it is a temporary condition however that you expect to recover from soon then it is a 503. I still don't care that this was caused by a downstream service. I only care that you tell me that you expect to recover soon, so I should retry after a while.

This is what w3.org states:

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   **temporary** overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a **temporary** condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay **MAY** be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client **SHOULD**
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

What you can (and really always should) do, is to return an error message in the body. If your api is a json api, then you should return a json formatted error message.

Don't think about looking good. Think about being explicit and predictable. The server encountered an unexpected condition, which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Edit: You mention databases, and in the case of a database timeout it is most definitely a 500.

/JP

Comment: yeah, the DB was a bad example and I agree on that one. The one that really concerns me in the actual case I'm talking about is the upstream service.  I take your point about the client not caring, but as a client I *do* care what kind of 500 it is, because some imply temporary problems, some imply specific resources, and some imply that the whole app crashed (500). I understand what you mean about 'looking good', but what I'm really concerned with is sending the right information to my clients so that they can handle it correctly.

Comment: Can you give a specific scenario? What kind of service is unavailable and why is it unavailable. What exactly do you want the client to do in that case.

Comment: but what about `502`?

Comment: @MikeB the anwer applies to all 5xx status, it doesn't matter.

Comment: All mention of `downstream` should be upstream in the answer I think. If and API depends on a service, that service is upstream from the API. The user or client is always downstream.

Comment: @dhwang The answer clarifies 500 & 503, but does not clarify 502. Can 502 be appropriate here?

Comment: @MikeB I wouldn't use a specific 5xx status for what I think  you're trying to accomplish. So, if you look at the 5xx status they are mostly ambiguous about what exactly happened, except to show that an exception happened. 502 is the closest to what you want to convey, but why use HTTP status for REST API error?
* First, I've seen Ops/DevOps misinterpret the HTTP status thinking it was an issue with HTTP level proxy.
* Second, REST API are allowed respond with Exception JSON, for example: I use

Comment: * Second, REST API are allowed respond with Exception JSON,  something like: `{ status: 500, code: DEPENDENCY_ERROR, message: "error in upstream services" }`

Comment: @dhwang I presume you agree with this answer saying to always use `500`. But I agree with the asker that `internal server error` feels wrong when the problem is with some other server, not mine. I feel like this situation could use its own `4xx` code.

Comment: @MikeB Yes, I agree REST API should return 500 even if source of exception is another service upstream because it doesn't matter where the origin is. The client to the REST API only knows about the REST endpoint (a black box). It feels wrong to the asker only because he is looking at the REST API as a white box. The job of the REST API is to provide an exception message tht is *useful* for 1) API client to handle the exception and 2) for the user to take action with if possible. So that means  the REST API should return 4XX only if the user can do something with it.

Answer (score 3):

It should be more like whatever u receive from upstream service, if its  503: Service Unavailable then you return  503: Service Unavailable  if its 500, you also return 500